# Linear Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

Question:

Consider $V=C([0,1])$ endowed with the norm $||f||=\sup_{0 \leq x \leq 1}|f(x)|$. Provide conditions on $K: [0,1] \times [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (the more general the better) so that the operator $T$ defined as $(Tf)(x)=\displaystyle\int_0^1 K(x,y)f(y)dy$ is a bounded linear operator from $V$ to $V$.

Attempt:

I know that a linear operator is bounded if $\exists$ $N>0$ such that $||Tx|| \leq N||x||$ for all $x \in X$. I think the idea of this problem is to take the maximum value of $K$, but I am having a hard time formalizing this.

Comment: Triangle inequality for integral; $K$ needs not to be bounded.

Comment: Perhaps first do a simplified problem.  Suppose it does not depend on $x$.  What type of function $k$ satisfies $\int_0^1 |k(y)f(y)|\,dy < \infty$ for all $f \in C[0,1]$?

Comment: To add to the above comment, consider a convolution-type kernel $K$ (so that $Tf(x)=\int_{[0,1]}K(x-y)f(y)\,dy$). Are you familiar with any $L^p$ inequalities?

Comment: The simplest assumption could be $K(x,y)$  continuous on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ and the norm is bounded by the maximal value of $|K(x,y)|.$ It may be  relaxed: the norm is bounded by $\sup_x\int |K(x,y)|\,dy$ and the functions $x\to K(x,y)$ are continuous uniformly with respect to $y.$

Comment: @GEdgar Would a constant function $k$ satisfy $\displaystyle\int_0^1 |k(y)f(y)|dy< \infty$ for all $f \in C[0,1]$?

Comment: @yona Which inequality are you talking about?

Comment: For the comment of @GEdgar , I'm thinking of H\"older's inequality. For my comment, I'm thinking of Young's inequality. The $L^\infty$ norm is equivalent to the sup norm on $C[0,1]$.